# How to Solve Trust Boundry violation result for Veracode scan?

Tags: java, jsp, veracode, scriptlet

I am getting violation for below line

```
request.getSession().setAttribute(Constants.DATA_LIST,dataList);
```

where `dataList` is `ArrayList`

```
dataList=(ArrayList)request.getSession().getAttribute(Constants.DATA_TRANSFER_OBJECT);
```

and `Constants.DATA_LIST` returns `String`.

Someone please help me how to fix this to avoid trust boundry violation flaw.

Answer (score 0):

The violation is occurring because you're storing untrusted data (passed in from the request) along with trusted data (the session).  The fix would would be to either not store the data together, or to validate & sanitize the untrusted data to make it trusted.

Keep in mind that "Trust Boundry Violation" doesn't actually mean there's a vulnerability, it just means that it would make it easier for a developer to make an error and trust untrusted code/values.

Answer (score -1):

Got the fix.
You need to add setter,getter for that arraylist and use getter to get arraylist.

Comment: can you share a code snippet of how you fixed this?

Comment: Simply adding a getter/setter is not actually solving the violation, it's just confusing the tool enough that it can no longer pick up the violation.